# .deb file installed, but dpkg -L library says it's not installed

Tags: dpkg

I installed ballerina programming laguage by following [this](https://ballerina.io/learn/getting-started/#installing-ballerina) . I installed this by **.deb** file. Now when I run `ballerina -v` from anywhere it outputs the version correctly.

I need to configure a VSCode plugin, which needs the path. But the path I entered by getting executed the command `which ballerina`, doesn't work (gives error as that's not the correct path). Then I tried to see where I installed the package from .deb file by following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/295322/linux-dpkg-where-does-it-install-to), I'm getting an error like this.

```
dpkg-query: package 'ballerina-platform-linux-installer-x64-0.975.1.deb' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents
```

Why's that ? How can I get the exact path I installed the above package ?

Comment: `dpkg -L`'s argument should be the package's name, not the deb file's. Run `dpkg --info ballerina-platform-linux-installer-x64-0.975.1.deb | grep Package` to get the package name, and run `dpkg -L` with that.

Comment: @muru Good as an answer

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I have a feeling this will immediately segue into the actual problem with this plugin.

Comment: @muru thanks. That worked. Didn't know about it. Then the first answer with most votes in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/295322/linux-dpkg-where-does-it-install-to) is wrong right ?  He has mentioned to run `dpkg -L library.deb`

Comment: @PankajaParanavitharana that would be wrong, yes.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -L`'s argument should be the package's name, not the deb file's (which can be named anything and have no actual relation to the package metadata).

To get the package name:

```
dpkg --info ballerina-platform-linux-installer-x64-0.975.1.deb | grep Package
```

and run `dpkg -L` with that package name.

Of course, if the deb file you have is the one you installed, you can inspect it directly:

```
dpkg --contents ballerina-platform-linux-installer-x64-0.975.1.deb
```

Use the package name and `dpkg -L` if the deb file you have is of a different version from the one you have installed, and this method if both are the same version.